# Updating percentages to set decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, type-conversion

I have a column of percentages, expressed as follows:

```
----------
usertxt2
----------
25%
26
NULL
a%

23.00%
23.6578
```

I need to convert all numbers to a fixed format of xx.xx% so that the column would appear as

```
----------
usertxt2
----------
25.00%
26.00%
NULL
NULL
NULL
23.00%
23.66%
```

So far, I have tried initially removing the LEFT() function to remove the % character then converting to decimal using the CAST() function and using the CASE WHEN function to ignore blank, non-numeric characters and NULL values. How can I remove the % character and convert to numeric whilst ignoring the blank and non-numeric characters?

Comment: You better store numbers in numeric columns. Storing them in `varchar` is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
update t
    set usertxt2 = cast(try_cast(replace(usertxt2, '%', '') as decimal(5, 2)) as varchar(255)) + '%'
```

This uses `try_cast()` to detect valid numbers.